# JAXB map not unmarshalling although marshalling is working correctly

Tags: java, jaxb

I've been struggling around with JAXB for two days now and I am stuck at the last problem i have encountered, which I can't seem to solve by myself because it's a very specific problem and google couldn't help me..

I want to marshal and unmarshal a HashMap of two custom types, therefore i wrote a XmlAdapter to marshal everything correctly. In addition I have cyclic references in there which I solved by creating a own Reference class that is used only for this map.

The XmlAdapter solution I have from here: [JAXB Map adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847343/jaxb-map-adapter)

..and the cyclic reference solution is from here: [JAXB Annotations - How do I make a list of XmlIDRef elements have the id value as an attribute instead of element body text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150263/jaxb-annotations-how-do-i-make-a-list-of-xmlidref-elements-have-the-id-value-a)

Below my solution:

This is the class that needs to be (un)marshalled:

RoomModel.java:

```
package at.jku.buildingsimulator.model;

import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import at.jku.buildingsimulator.MainApp;
import at.jku.buildingsimulator.jaxb.ConnectionAdapter;
import at.jku.buildingsimulator.jaxb.SensorAdapter;
import at.jku.indoorpersontracker.model.Room;
import at.jku.indoorpersontracker.sensor.Sensor;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;

@XmlType(name = "RoomModel")
public class RoomModel {

    @XmlType(name = "WallPosition")
    public static enum WallPosition {
        LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM, NOT_ADJACENT, DIFFERENT_FLOOR, OUTSIDE;

        public static WallPosition opposite(WallPosition position) {
            switch(position) {
            case LEFT: return RIGHT;
            case RIGHT: return LEFT;
            case TOP: return BOTTOM;
            case BOTTOM: return TOP;
            case NOT_ADJACENT: return NOT_ADJACENT;
            case DIFFERENT_FLOOR: return DIFFERENT_FLOOR;
            case OUTSIDE: return OUTSIDE;
            default: return DIFFERENT_FLOOR;
            }
        }
    }

    private IntegerProperty roomNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private ObservableSet<Sensor> sensors = FXCollections.observableSet();
    private ObservableSet<PersonModel> persons = FXCollections.observableSet();
    private ObservableSet<DeviceModel> devices = FXCollections.observableSet();
    private ObservableMap<WallPosition, RoomModel> connectedRooms = FXCollections.observableHashMap();
    private Room room;  // the underlying room for the indoorpersontracker

    public RoomModel() { this(-1); }

    public RoomModel(int roomNumber) {
        this.roomNumber.set(roomNumber);
        this.room = MainApp.getInstance().getTracker().getRoom(roomNumber);

        if(this.room == null) {
            this.room = new Room(roomNumber);
//          MainApp.getInstance().getTracker().addRoom(room);
        }
    }

    /**
     * connect this room with another room
     * @param other
     * @param isConnected true if the rooms are connected or false if they are disconnected
     * @param position the position where the door is at
     */
    public void setConnected(RoomModel other, boolean isConnected, WallPosition position) {
        if (isConnected == true && !connectedRooms.containsValue(other)) { // prevent endless loop
            if(this != BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance())
                connectedRooms.put(position, other);
            System.out.println("adding connection: " + position + ": " + other.getRoomNumber()); // TODO remove
            other.setConnected(this, true, WallPosition.opposite(position));    // also tell the other room that it is connected with this room

            if(this == BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance()) {
                other.getRoom().setHasEntrance(true);
            } else if(other == BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance()) {
                room.setHasEntrance(true);
            } else {
                room.setConnected(other.getRoom(), true); // also connect the library rooms
            }
        } else if (isConnected == false && connectedRooms.containsValue(other)) {
            if(this != BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance())
                connectedRooms.remove(position);
            other.setConnected(this, false, WallPosition.opposite(position));

            if(this == BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance()) {
                other.getRoom().setHasEntrance(false);
            } else if(other == BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance()) {
                room.setHasEntrance(false);
            } else {
                room.setConnected(other.getRoom(), false);
            }
        }
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "connections")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ConnectionAdapter.class)
//  @XmlElements({ @XmlElement(name = "WallPosition", type = WallPosition.class),  @XmlElement(name = "RoomModel", type = RoomModelRef.class) })
    public ObservableMap<WallPosition, RoomModel> getConnected() {
        return this.connectedRooms;
    }

    // TODO remove
    public void setConnected(ObservableMap<WallPosition, RoomModel> connections) {
        this.connectedRooms = connections;
    }

    public void setHasEntrance(boolean hasEntrance, WallPosition position) {
        this.room.setHasEntrance(hasEntrance);

        // connect this room with the outside via this wall to draw a door
        if(hasEntrance)
            this.connectedRooms.put(position, BuildingModel.getSingleton().getOutsideInstance());
        else
            this.connectedRooms.remove(position);
    }

    public boolean getHasEntrance() {
        return this.room.getHasEntrance();
    }

    public final IntegerProperty roomNumberProperty() {
        return this.roomNumber;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = "roomNumber", required = true)
    public final int getRoomNumber() {
        return this.roomNumberProperty().get();
    }   

    @XmlTransient
    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void addSensor(Sensor sensor) {
        sensors.add(sensor);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "Sensor")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(SensorAdapter.class)
    public ObservableSet<Sensor> getSensors() {
        return sensors;
    }

    public void addPerson(PersonModel person) {
        persons.add(person);
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public ObservableSet<PersonModel> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void removePerson(PersonModel person) {
        persons.remove(person);
    }

    public void addDevice(DeviceModel device) {
        devices.add(device);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "DeviceModel", type = DeviceModel.class)
    public ObservableSet<DeviceModel> getDevices() {
        return devices;
    }

    public void removeSensor(Sensor sensor) {
        sensors.remove(sensor);
        System.err.println("Sensor model removed from room " + getRoomNumber());
    }

    public void removeDevice(DeviceModel deviceModel) {
        devices.remove(deviceModel);
    }

    public boolean hasTopWallDoor() {
        return connectedRooms.containsKey(WallPosition.TOP);
    }

    public boolean hasBottomWallDoor() {
        return connectedRooms.containsKey(WallPosition.BOTTOM);
    }

    public boolean hasLeftWallDoor() {
        return connectedRooms.containsKey(WallPosition.LEFT);
    }

    public boolean hasRightWallDoor() {
        return connectedRooms.containsKey(WallPosition.RIGHT);
    }

    public void setRoomNumber(int roomNumber) {
        this.roomNumber.set(roomNumber);
        this.room.setRoomNumber(roomNumber);

        // migrate the persons in this room to the new room number
        /*SimulatedSensor tempSensor = new SimulatedSensor(0);
//      tempSensor.setRoom(room); TODO is currently in FloorModel.setRoomNoOffset, move to here if setting room number can be done elsewhere (could cause a problem with order then, add a Platform.runLater() here to resolve this)
        MainApp.getInstance().getTracker().addSensor(tempSensor, roomNumber);
        for(PersonModel person : persons) {
            tempSensor.detectPerson(person.getName());
        }
        MainApp.getInstance().getTracker().removeSensor(tempSensor);*/
    }

    public boolean isConnectedWith(RoomModel roomModel) {
        return connectedRooms.containsValue(roomModel);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == this) {
            return true;
        } else if(obj instanceof RoomModel) {
            RoomModel roomModel = (RoomModel)obj;
            return roomModel.room.equals(this.room);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @XmlID
    public String getId() {
        return String.valueOf(getRoomNumber());
    }

    void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller u, Object parent) {
          System.err.println("connections: " + connectedRooms.size());
    }

}
```

ConnectionAdapter.java:

```
package at.jku.buildingsimulator.jaxb;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel;
import at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel.WallPosition;

public class ConnectionAdapter extends XmlAdapter<ConnectionAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<WallPosition, RoomModel>> {

    public static class AdaptedMap {

        //@XmlVariableNode("key")
        @XmlElement(name = "connection", type = AdaptedEntry.class)
        List<AdaptedEntry> entries = new ArrayList<AdaptedEntry>();

    }

    public static class AdaptedEntry {

        @XmlElement(name = "WallPosition")
        public WallPosition key;

        @XmlElement(name="RoomModel")
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RoomModelAdapter.class)
        public RoomModel value;

    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<WallPosition, RoomModel> map) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        for(Entry<WallPosition, RoomModel> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry = new AdaptedEntry();
            adaptedEntry.key = entry.getKey();
            adaptedEntry.value = entry.getValue();
            adaptedMap.entries.add(adaptedEntry);
        }
        return adaptedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<WallPosition, RoomModel> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        List<AdaptedEntry> adaptedEntries = adaptedMap.entries;
        Map<WallPosition, RoomModel> map = new HashMap<>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for(AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : adaptedEntries) {
            map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
        }
        System.err.println("unmarshal: " + map.size());
        for(Entry<WallPosition, RoomModel> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.err.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

RoomModelAdapter.java:

```
package at.jku.buildingsimulator.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

import at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel;

public class RoomModelAdapter extends XmlAdapter<RoomModelRef, RoomModel>{

    @Override
    public RoomModelRef marshal(RoomModel v) throws Exception {
        return new RoomModelRef(v);
    }

    @Override
    public RoomModel unmarshal(RoomModelRef v) throws Exception {
        return v.roomModel;
    }

}
```

RoomModelRef.java:

```
package at.jku.buildingsimulator.jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlIDREF;

import at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel;

public class RoomModelRef {

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute(name = "ref")
    RoomModel roomModel;

    public RoomModelRef() { }

    public RoomModelRef(RoomModel roomModel) {
        this.roomModel = roomModel;
    }

}
```

And here a resulting example .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<BuildingModel>
    <FloorModel floorNo="1" numRooms="4" roomNoOffset="0">
        <roomModels>
            <entry>
                <key>1</key>
                <value roomNumber="1">
                    <connections>
                        <connection>
                            <WallPosition>RIGHT</WallPosition>
                            <RoomModel ref="2"/>
                        </connection>
                    </connections>
                    <id>1</id>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>2</key>
                <value roomNumber="2">
                    <connections>
                        <connection>
                            <WallPosition>LEFT</WallPosition>
                            <RoomModel ref="1"/>
                        </connection>
                        <connection>
                            <WallPosition>BOTTOM</WallPosition>
                            <RoomModel ref="4"/>
                        </connection>
                    </connections>
                    <id>2</id>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>3</key>
                <value roomNumber="3">
                    <connections/>
                    <id>3</id>
                </value>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <key>4</key>
                <value roomNumber="4">
                    <connections>
                        <connection>
                            <WallPosition>RIGHT</WallPosition>
                            <RoomModel ref="0"/>
                        </connection>
                        <connection>
                            <WallPosition>TOP</WallPosition>
                            <RoomModel ref="2"/>
                        </connection>
                    </connections>
                    <id>4</id>
                </value>
            </entry>
        </roomModels>
    </FloorModel>
    <outsideInstance roomNumber="0">
        <connections/>
        <id>0</id>
    </outsideInstance>
    <persons/>
</BuildingModel>
```

I also put some debug lines in there: 
In ConnectionAdapter at unmarshal() method it says: "unmarshal: 1" for the first room.
And in RoomModel at afterUnmarshal() it says: "connections: 0" for the first room, which I don't quite get because obviously the unmarshalling works in ConnectionAdapter, so the error must be somewhere between there.

I hope someone is taking the time to give it a "quick" look, unfortunately i cannot post the whole model code as it is very complex and not related to this issue.

Edit: okay I printed out the unmarshalled map now in the unmarshall() method in ConnectionAdapter:

```
@Override
    public Map<WallPosition, RoomModel> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        List<AdaptedEntry> adaptedEntries = adaptedMap.entries;
        Map<WallPosition, RoomModel> map = new HashMap<>(adaptedEntries.size());
        for(AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : adaptedEntries) {
            map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
        }
        System.err.println("unmarshal: " + map.size());
        for(Entry<WallPosition, RoomModel> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.err.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
        }
        return map;
    }
```

which is resulting in follwing output:

```
unmarshal: 1
RIGHT, null
connections: 0
unmarshal: 2
LEFT, at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel@21f654e2
BOTTOM, null
connections: 0
unmarshal: 0
connections: 0
unmarshal: 2
RIGHT, null
TOP, at.jku.buildingsimulator.model.RoomModel@2b13651e
connections: 0
Rooms in here: 4
unmarshal: 0
connections: 0
```

So apparently the RoomModel (per reference) is not unmarshalled correctly every time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I came up with a solution myself now.

The problem was the order of unmarshalling, which caused that not all RoomModels have been read in already when the references in the connections were read. I thought JAXB would be so intelligent to save this reference and resolve it later but nah, it's not.

I solved the problem by simply reworking my model, in particular i just changed the type of the map connectedRooms to `<WallPosition, Integer>` to remove circular references and to ease serialization. I really don't know why i thought about that earlier and it gives me thrills when I think about the work and time i spent for this problem, but at least I got some experience with circular references and that the order of (un)marshalling matters.

I don't know if this thread should be deleted or if it could help anybody else, for me at least this can be closed.